# jQuery CSS bug in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a bug in IE8 when trying to get a property from css for an element with background image.

```
el.css({ 'background-position': "10px 10px"}); //set some 
alert(el.css("background-position")); //get the value
```

In Opera, FF, Chrome, Safari works I get "10px 10px". Not in IE8 where I get undefined.
I opened a [bug report](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5210), but until then what do you think it will be a good workaround this  problem. How should I get this values in some another way?

Comment: For posterity: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4295 is the main bug report for this issue. As of this writing it's set to "patch welcome", but there's no fix. Users will have to test cross-browser for any grouped CSS properties like this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>[this](http://dextrose.be/2008/11/10/jquery-background-position-and-internet-explorer/) should help.</s>

it links to [jquery ticket 2462](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2462) which is also interesting

**Edit** first link dead, [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130525070607/http://dextrose.be/2008/11/10/jquery-background-position-and-internet-explorer) to the rescue.

And, just in case archive.org ever packs up, here is the contents of the dextrose blog post.

> jQuery (at least up till version 1.2.6) has a problem with Internet
>   Explorer when asking the background-position of an object.
>
> ```
> $('h1:first').css('background-position');
> ```
>
> In the other A-grade browsers, you get 2 values (in px or %)
>   representing respectively the x-position and y-position of the
>   element. In Internet Explorer (6 and 7) you get undefined. The problem
>   is that IE doesn't know what background-position is, it only knows 2
>   other calls: background-position-x and background-position-y. Here is
>   a slice of JavaScript code to handle this problem.
>
> ```
> (function($) {
>   jQuery.fn.backgroundPosition = function() {
>     var p = $(this).css('background-position');
>     if(typeof(p) === 'undefined') 
>         return $(this).css('background-position-x') 
>                + ' ' + $(this).css('background-position-y');
>     else return p;
>   };
> })(jQuery);
> ```
>
> You can now use this jQuery plugin to get the background-position of
>   an element:
>
> ```
> $('h1:first').backgroundPosition();
> ```

Comment: This is the problem writing quickly answers with only links: if the link expires the answer becomes useful.

Comment: Really? A downvote on an almost 3 year old question because of link rot?

Comment: I'm Sorry, but the "copy pasted link" answers really thwarts me, also I think it express a poor effort. Thanks for improve the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I've never tried this but i found that by requesting the positions individually u get a result, so:

```
alert(el.css("background-position-y")); //get the y value
alert(el.css("background-position-x")); //get the x value
```

then you can combine the two :)

Answer (score 1):

If you alert the background-property, then you'd also get the position. A very bad workaround, but the first I could think of...

```
alert(el.css("background")); //url(some/url/to/image.jpg) no-repeat 10px 10px
```

And then you'd have to just get out the numerical values that are followed by "px"

Comment: technically this should work but it doesn't because the property was set with css function and is not added to the real css but inserted dynamicly in the style attribute

Answer (score 1):

I will finally parse them from:

```
alert(el.attr('style')); // this seems to work in all browsers
```