# select dom elements with specified css rules set

Tags: jquery

I know how to select elements by attribute like this:

```
<input value="myvalue" />
$('input[value="myvalue"]')
```

But how it is possible to select dom elements with specified css rules set. 
For example i need to select all elements with css "background-position" set;

Comment: use :input instead of input because :input select all kind of input element like input,button,submit,radio,checkbox etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for this, but you could use a `.filter()` to reduce a selector to suit your needs:

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).css('backgroundPosition')); // tests for existence
});
```

However, the problem here is that even if 'background-position' isn't set, *some* browsers set it to default values. You'll have to compare against those default values, but you won't be able to tell if those values were explicitly set in a stylesheet or not.

(**Update:** IE8 returns `$(this).css('backgroundPosition')` as "undefined" no matter what. The [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420913/jquery-css-bug-in-ie8) is to test for 'backgroundPositionX' and/or 'backgroundPositionY' individually. However, while the defaults *should* be "0%", IE8 reports a default of "0px" instead. Test for both.)

(**Update 2:** Firefox doesn't return individual properties, only combined 'background-position'; IE8 doesn't return combined, only individual. Webkit will do both.)

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return ($(this).css('backgroundPosition') !== "0% 0%" // firefox, webkit
        && $(this).css('backgroundPositionX') !== "0px"  // ie8
        && $(this).css('backgroundPositionY') !== "0px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/s8dx2/23/

Comment: I have a feeling this will give false positives in some browsers.

Comment: In Chrome at least this will return all `div` elements whether you've set `background-position` or not (`background-position` is `0% 0%` unless you've set it as something else): http://jsfiddle.net/LGmEp/

Comment: Yes, it seems to be heavily browser-dependent -- and not all CSS attributes have default values.

Comment: This is why cross-browser testing is so important, even with jQuery leveling the field. Interested parties should look at the bug report at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4295 , but the upshot is that different browsers report grouped CSS properties like `margin` and `border` very differently, and jQuery will not (at present) re-combine them.